# Wait for Field to equal value not working

Tags: workflow

I have a calculated column that tells me how many days are left on a warranty.   I have a workflow that checks this value and if it is more than 60 days to wait until field to equal 60  and then it is suppose to email me.

The problem is now that I've started the workflow it is stuck on waiting for 60 days and I notice that the calculated column has stopped counting down also.   Does this freeze the calculated column until something manually changes it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculated columns only calculate when an update occurs for that item. You may need to transfer the logic of the calculation to your workflow. That way whenever the workflow runs, the logic with execute and you will get back the correct value without having to update the list item.

Comment: I guess I didn't know that.   There are so many limitation in SharePoint.   Thanks for the quick response.